# ServerAlias stopped working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualhost, serveralias

I had this working, then my VM server crashed.

I'm running Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox. Now I'm trying to add some server aliases, but it's not working.

In my 'sites-enabled' folder I have a file called `mysite.com`. This has the following data:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.mysite.com, sub1.mysite.com, sub2.mysite.com

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/storelocator/>
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I'm still not able to access the site using sub1.mysite.com. It only shows me the folders in www root folder.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Include the output of `apache2ctl -S` in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing your commas. I've always used spaces to delimit the hostnames (same goes for `/etc/hosts` as well)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions seem totally correct to me. However this rather sounds like a DNS issue. Depending on your host, try refresh you DNS cache (depending on your OS) and check if sub1.mysite.com matches the IP of your VM.

Comment: Since this is on a VirtualServer on my machine (running Win7) I'm not sure I have a DNS chache? Also, something I forgot to mention. I'm not getting a blank page. The page shows me the folders in www root folder.

Comment: I'm able to ping sub1.mysite.com. So it's def. DNS problem.

Comment: I never put up `ServerAlias` in one line, but one under the other. So this slipped past my scope here. Glad the comma-issue solved it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove replace the ServerAlias line entry as given below, restart Apache and then try ?

```
ServerAlias www.mysite.com sub1.mysite.com sub2.mysite.com


sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Mike got onto this first :-)